# Trouble with a cursor loop in an SQL event

Tags: mariadb

My current code:

```
CREATE EVENT lifeinsurance_reset
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
BEGIN 
    DECLARE Cur = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `char_id` FROM `life_insurance` WHERE `renewal_date` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    
    OPEN Cur
        LOOP
            UPDATE `characters` SET `bank` = `bank` - 25000 WHERE `id` = Cur.char_id;
            UPDATE `life_insurance` SET `renewal_date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE `char_id` = Cur.char_id
        END LOOP
    CLOSE Cur
END
```

Which results in a syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN 
    DECLARE Cur = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `char_id` FROM `life_insurance...' at line 7
```

I've done a lot of google searches regarding this, a lot of which stated I needed to use a delimiter. Upon trying that, with the following code, I get an error as well.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE EVENT lifeinsurance_reset
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
BEGIN 
    DECLARE Cur = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `char_id` FROM `life_insurance` WHERE `renewal_date` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    
    OPEN Cur
        LOOP
            UPDATE `characters` SET `bank` = `bank` - 25000 WHERE `id` = Cur.char_id;
            UPDATE `life_insurance` SET `renewal_date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE `char_id` = Cur.char_id
        END LOOP
    CLOSE Cur
END$$
delimiter;

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$
CREATE EVENT lifeinsurance_reset
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS...' at line 1
```

I'm not very well-versed in SQL, so any help would be appreciated.
For context, I'm trying to loop through all the rows in an insurance table for a game, if the renewal date is past current timestamp, it'll auto deduct money from the characters bank and reset the renewal date to a month from now.

Comment: You can remove the `ENABLE` as events are enabled by default. There a missing `;` needed at the end of the `SELECT` and the end of the 2nd `UPDATE`, and after `END LOOP` and after `CLOSE Cur`. Looks like you might have a little syntax mix-up with procedures, `EVENTS` do not have a `BEGIN` or `END`, just a `DO` where the BEGIN is located, then the SQL, there is no END. See the [create event](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-event/) docs for some examples.

Comment: @PaulT. Awesome, thanks for the response. I'll try and fix it up.

Comment: Ok. I don't know that I've ever seen a cursor used in an `EVENT` handling, so I'd be curious to know if that works or not. Please update in another comment if there may be other error(s).